# Bash script not running via cron and sh , but runs fine with ./filename.sh

Tags: bash, cron

I have a code which crontab is not able to run

i am using ./filename.sh to run it. when i do this manually this runs fine

but via cron when i try

```
*/5 * * * * . /home/ubuntu/filename.sh >> /filename.sh
```

This doesn't work

```
for ((i=0; i<retries; i++)); do

    curl -1 --cipher ALL --connect-timeout 90 -T $zip_name ftps://ftp.box.com/Backup/$zip_name --user admin:pas    [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && break

    echo "something went wrong, let's wait 6 seconds and retry"
    sleep 6
done

[[ $retries -eq i ]] && { echo "This email is being sent as a notifer of Failure, Support" | mail -s "Dump Failed" "asdfas4@gmail.com"  ; exit 1; }
```

Also when i run this using sh

it says `Syntax error: Bad for loop variable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, the shell of your `cron` is `dash` (not `bash`). In Ubuntu (and derivatives) `sh` is just a symlink for `dash`.

You can:

- Add a shebang at the top of of your script -- `#!/bin/bash` (or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`), **recommended approach**
- Run the script as an argument to `bash`: `/bin/bash /path/to/script.sh`, **moderately recommended**
- Set `SHELL=/bin/bash` in your `crontab` (**not recommended**), or even you can set the `SHELL` as `bash` for the run of any single command but again use the shebang approach

Also, always try to use absolute path to any file in `crontab` as `cron` runs with a modified `PATH`.

---

Now, even in `bash`, your `for` construct's syntax is incorrect, you need the arithmetic operator `(())`, not subshell (`()`):

```
for ((i=0; i<retries; i++)); do ...; done
```

Comment: added `#!/usr/bin/env bash` and also did (()) on for loop , it staill says that  Syntax error: Bad for loop variable

Comment: the modification that you said, i tried that.. the script works fine when i run it as ./filenam.sh but when i do sh filename.sh it still says BAD FOR LOOP VARIABLE

Comment: DON'T use `sh`!  It will ignore the #! line and use dash.  The `for` loop construct you are using is not supported by `sh`.

Answer (score 0):

If you source the script by `.` operator, then shebang `#!/bin/bash` in the script is ignored. The script is executed in the shell of your cron, which is not bash and it doesn't support for loop you are using.

Add shebang in your script and remove `.` from cron file:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/ubuntu/filename.sh >> /filename.sh
```

or just edit cron file in the following way:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash /home/ubuntu/filename.sh >> /filename.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use . when you are giving full path to the script, try running below command:

```
*/5 * * * *  /home/ubuntu/filename.sh
```

It should work, Let me know in case of more details.